# Django 1.5 bug with template "extends"?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my code.  As far as I can tell it may be a bug with Django 1.5.   I am running on windows. The templates, css, etc.. are being found no problem.  Semantically everything is being outputted to source correctly.  The problem is some sort of quirk when the browser renders the page, possibly a development server quirk.

The issue is very difficult to explain so I made a video and put it on YouTube.  The quirk only occurs if the the template has an "extends" in it.

[Video showing the quirk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ba4_QUqdOwg&feature=youtube_gdata)

Comment: If you use Firefox to inspect the web, do you see the same error?

Comment: Very interesting, I just downloaded the latest Firefox (26) and it does not show this quirk.  It displays perfectly.

Comment: I accepted the answer but the issue is weird because IE has the same problem.  It's only Firefox which does not glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question turns out to be the Visual Studio editor I was using.  The html layout page was being saved with BOM turned on.   You have to manually turn this off in Visual Studio.  Basically it was saving the page in a way Chrome did not understand completely.

Answer (score 2):

As you say in the comments, the problem is with `chrome` as far as I know the **Inspect Web** code is different from the **View Source** code, a blog's [post](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201009/inspect_element_is_not_the_same_as_view_source/) about this, maybe this can happen because a **chrome's bug** or I do not know if **Jquery** makes and inject or something like this, I do not think that this is a django's bug. So i think that you do not have to worry of all about this.